# MDX Mondrian : Convert seconds integer to time format "dd,hh,mm,ss"

Tags: mdx, pentaho, olap, mondrian

i wanna convert my integer input corresponding to the total number of seconds to time format :

**n days, hh,mm,ss**

**Example : 176553 seconds = 2 day , 01:02:33**

i have started by try this format:

```
    WITH MEMBER [Measures].[TIMECONVERTED] 
AS '[Measures].[Durees totales en secondes]/ 86400', FORMAT_STRING = "hh:mm:ss"
```

But that 'didn't work ,

(maybe because **[Measures].[Durees totales en secondes]** is numeric

so after googling i have found that solution , which also didn't work and here is the details :

here is my MDX script ( i executed it within jasperServer for OLAP displaying ):

```
with member [Measures].TIMECONVERTED as [Measures].[Durees totales en secondes]
 ,format_string 
   = 
    IIF(
      [Measures].TIMECONVERTED  < 1
     ,'d "days" hh:mm:ss'
     ,'"' + cstr(int([Measures].TIMECONVERTED )) + ' days" hh:mm:ss')
select NON EMPTY {
[Measures].TIMECONVERTED ,
[Measures].[Durees totales en minutes],
[Measures].[Durees totales en secondes],
[Measures].[Nombre appels repondus],
[Measures].[Nombre Appels sortants],
[Measures].[Durees appels repondus en minutes],
[Measures].[Durees appels sortants en minutes],
[Measures].[Durees appels repondus en secondes], 
[Measures].[Durees appels sortants en secondes]
} ON COLUMNS,
  NON EMPTY Crossjoin(Hierarchize({([Times.Time].[All Times.Times], [Agents.Agent].[All Agents.Agents])}), {[Clients.Client].[All Clients.Clients]}) ON ROWS
from [cube_durees_appels]
```

> That tells me that Mondrian doesn't know the "cstr" fonction

**Any propositions ??**

Answer (score 1):

[According to the Mondrian documentations](http://mondrian.pentaho.com/api/mondrian/olap/fun/CastFunDef.html) you have to use the Cast function instead.